# Flutter app does not show the Instagram image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to load the Instagram image in image.network(). But showing 'EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE'. Please help me to fix this error.
Thank you
I'm pasting my code here

```
children: <Widget>[
      Image.network('https://www.instagram.com/p/CE1PNcVpdO4/'),
    ],
```

Comment: You are not pointing to the image itself... but to the post that is html...

Comment: the image you are looking for is https://instagram.fcok6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/p1080x1080/118864589_319621276044893_8442342654742861754_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fcok6-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=ZA69B-zIGC4AX_EGp0o&tp=1&oh=7326fc637a4a28c016f4261846f66cf4&oe=5FF34BD8
but instead, you provided the Instagram page link,

Comment: Yes, that's the image in that post. But I need that post which I provided in the code. Is there any way to get that Instagram post in the flutter app? @Mr Random

Comment: Try the Instagram API or  web scraping

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Thank you @Mr Random

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your URL is passing a **WEB PAGE** not an **IMAGE**

image link should be like that

https://images.pexels.com/photos/5740932/pexels-photo-5740932.jpeg

with the format name.